# Ubuntu under proxmox with plesk installed, can't get to receive traffic from two interfaces at same time

Tags: lubuntu, netplan

I have plesk installed in a ubuntu vm under proxmox on ovh. I have an issue where I would like to have another ip available on plesk to users can use the other ip too. I've added correctly but it seems that it only works one at a time. If I add gateway4 to ens19, it will respond that ens, if I remove the gateway4, the new ip doesn't respond.

The network in proxmox is well configured as it accepts traffic from the new IP whenever I set up the gateway.

Any idea how can I configure netplan to be able to accept traffic from both ens at the same time?

this is what I have on netplan yaml:

```
network:
 version: 2
 renderer: networkd
 ethernets:
  ens18:
   dhcp4: yes
  ens19:
   dhcp4: no
   addresses: [publicIP/24]
   nameservers:
    addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
//   gateway4: [publicIP.254] -- this is not commented, just to show you which line I'm refering to
```

Hope someone can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have two public IPs on two separate interfaces and you want each of them to be used globally, you need to use a routing policy as described on https://netplan.io/reference/#routing.

Comment: can I get an example? @slangasek